# Generate random data using ETL tool

Tags: etl, talend

I want to generate random data that fits business rules across how the data will look.

The data has around 10 columns and 1000's of records.

A column value may also be dependent on another and there are potentially other business rules that affect the data.

Example data might look like this:

```
ID Deal_ID    No_of_trade price quantity start_date end_date
1  2014-10-14 50          100   70       2014-10-14 2014-10-15
2  2014-10-15 80          105   90       2014-10-15 2014-10-17
```

In this example, `start_date` is dependent on `deal_id` (deal_date) and
`end_date` is dependent on `start_date`

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you are expecting to be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you'll want to use a tRowGenerator to give you the main part of the data and then use a tMap to make some transformations to this data to give you the full output data.

A simple job might look something like:

[image: Job layout]

In this we configure the tRowGenerator as so:

[image: tRowGenerator configuration]

Which gives us a date for the `Deal_id`, random integers for the number of trades, price and quantity and finally a random integer for the amount of days trading which we will add to our `start_date` to get an `end_date`.

After this, we sort using a tSortRow on the `Deal_id` field so that they are in ascending order.

And then finally we use a tMap to transform the data to your desired output:

[image: tMap configuration]

This gives us an `ID` using the `Numeric.sequence` function in Talend, sets `start_date` to be the same as the `Deal_id` and then has an `end_date` that is the randomly generated amount of days later than the `start_date` that we generated in the tRowGenerator.

Output looks something like this:

```
.---+----------+-----------+-----+--------+----------+----------.
|                           tLogRow_7                           |
|=--+----------+-----------+-----+--------+----------+---------=|
|id |Deal_Id   |No_of_Trade|Price|Quantity|Start_Date|End_Date  |
|=--+----------+-----------+-----+--------+----------+---------=|
|1  |01-10-2014|86         |144  |136     |01-10-2014|06-10-2014|
|2  |02-10-2014|59         |138  |114     |02-10-2014|04-10-2014|
|3  |03-10-2014|86         |103  |51      |03-10-2014|09-10-2014|
|4  |04-10-2014|37         |126  |50      |04-10-2014|08-10-2014|
|5  |04-10-2014|49         |115  |80      |04-10-2014|06-10-2014|
|6  |04-10-2014|54         |112  |26      |04-10-2014|08-10-2014|
...
|95 |23-12-2014|2          |138  |72      |23-12-2014|27-12-2014|
|96 |23-12-2014|94         |123  |120     |23-12-2014|26-12-2014|
|97 |26-12-2014|33         |107  |131     |26-12-2014|28-12-2014|
|98 |27-12-2014|36         |125  |55      |27-12-2014|02-01-2015|
|99 |29-12-2014|59         |109  |55      |29-12-2014|03-01-2015|
|100|31-12-2014|44         |141  |88      |31-12-2014|02-01-2015|
'---+----------+-----------+-----+--------+----------+----------'
```